# Windows application or website

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, architecture

I want to write a warehouse program which has near 80 clients.My program has to make some reports and control entrance and exit of commodities in warehouse and store data in SQL Server Database.I need to know that which one is better: using windows application which give me a lot of feathers or creating website which reduce my ability in using objects?I have to mention that my clients will not increase.

Comment: Why would a web site reduce your ability to use objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you create a webservice which does all the actual work. In that way it's quite easy to build either a windows app, a web app or both.

It's really easy if you use WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that it reduces your ability to use objects ?

I would always go with web application and not CSA (Client Server Application. 
Reasons (Source: http://www.eforcesoftware.com/brochures/Web%20Benefits%20over%20Client%20Server%20Technology.pdf)

Web applications are easier to deploy (install on the server only) Gives workers 
secure, easy and instant access to enterprise applications, information, 
processes and people, no matter where they are located, from anywhere, at 
anytime, using any device, over any connection.
o CSAs must have software installed on both the client and the server.  You 
must have people update both sides for software updates and upgrades

 Web applications give easier access (all you need is a secure internet connection 
and a browser)
o CSAs need to have the client piece installed and are more difficult to 
share outside a firewall
o CSAs run slowly when you are not on the same network

 Web applications are centrally administered.  Enables IT staffs to manage the 
centralized management of applications, simplifying their deployment, monitoring 
and measurement.
o CSAs are more complex to centrally administer
 Web applications require less processing power on the client
o CSAs require more processing power on clients and are more expensive

 Web applications are more flexible (can be tailored to your needs easier).  They 
can easily be integrated with other agency systems and databases to provide a 
seamless Agency wide system.
o CSAs are delivered as binary applications and are harder to customize

 Web applications don’t require much training (everyone knows how to use a web 
browsers and surf the Internet)
o CSA require more detailed training and takes more time for users to get 
comfortable and then adopt the new system.

Comment: Could he not embed a browser app in the win app and have WCF services hosted on server? I mean does it have to be ASP/web app always for this problem?

Comment: Sure it could be. But in that case, doesn't he need to distribute that win app to each of its client. Why not have it publish as web app and give url to the clients (Assume they have the web browser )

Comment: On the other hand: web apps have to deal with browser incompatibilities, subtle Javascript / CSS differences, IIS / hosting configurations and headaches.... it's not all just pros for web apps...

Comment: Yea as marc says, browser incompatiblity issues.

Answer (score 0):

How website does reduce your ability to using objects? I am sure the server side of programming is still C# though if you use ASP.NET. Plus ASP.NET gives you a lot more flexibility in handling more user connections via IIS.

Comment: You say `ASP` but you really mean `ASP.NET` - right? Not the horrid old "classic ASP with VBScript" ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about **[Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/)**?

It's basically a browser-plugin, but the Silverlight apps are almost as good as "real" Windows apps (Silverlight is a stripped-down WPF, basically).

It's a bit the best of both worlds - rich and powerful UI, and basically installed/deployed on a web server.